# Unit Testing pattern

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns

I am looking for a solution/pattern for the following unit testing case.

**The case:**

Let's pretend that we have three classes, A,B,C each with one method. A's method calls B's method which calls C's method. So, A->B->C. Each method take one input (Input A for method A, input B, input C). The resulting output of the call to method A, would be a tree structure such as:

Root (created from method A)
  -- Node B (created from method B)
     -- Node C1
     -- Node C2 (both created from method C)

For me unit testing is about testing the output from input of a method in isolation. So, we would write unit tests for each of the methods above. Because the tests are written in isolation, we would mock the method B when writing unit tests for method A, and mock the method C when writing unit test cases for method B.

So far, all is good, we can write expectations on the output for each method to make sure that the resulting tree structure is respected.

**The problem:**

Let's now add another class which would call method B so that we also have the following call chain: D->B->C. The resulting root tree would look like this:

- Root D

  - Node B

    - Node C1
    - Node C2

During the development, someone realise that the requirement for method A was misunderstood and the tree result should have looked like this:

- Root A

  - Node B

    - Node C

Happily the developer would change the method C so that the output only returns one Node rather than two. He would change the unit tests so that it reflects those changes. 
However, method D requirements should not have changed, and the output of that method should still have Node C1 and Node C2.

**The question:**

How would you have written your unit tests so that the second developer would have been alerted of breaking change he would have introduced for method D? I would rather avoid integration tests which would seem the best fit here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with isolated unit tests (which I do for most of my central objects since I find it nearly impossible to write the right amount of integrated tests with the right depth and keep them fast), an interesting approach is Joe Rainsberger's [Contract and Collaboration Tests](http://b-speaking.blogspot.be/search/label/integration%20tests). He raises the point that you shouldn't mock out a dependency to behave some way in a test unless you have corresponding Contract tests ensuring that concrete implementations of that dependency do behave that way in the real world.

In your example, saying that "method C now only returns one Node rather than two" means **changing C's contract** and its contract tests accordingly. That introduces the possibility for a mocked C to become out of sync with the new contract, therefore you should look in your tests everywhere C is mocked and adjust the mocks if need be.

Which after careful examination of the existing tests would then lead you to realize that you don't really want to change the contract for method C but rather **introduce a new method C2** that suits the needs of A.

Rainsberger describes the process he uses to make sure he's got that reciprocity in tests [here](http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/2009/10/08/who-tests-the-contract-tests/). You can also watch the technique in action in [this video](http://www.jbrains.ca/permalink/the-worlds-best-intro-to-tdd-demo-video).

Answer (score 2):

You should have a mix of "pure¹" unit tests, impure unit test, integration (external resource hitting) tests and full stack tests (UI down). "Pure" unit tests are not the end of testing.

So you will end up with some of the follow types of test for each feature you develop:

- A Unit Test - Hit A in isolation - if the lower levels are complicated or hit an external resource.
- Also Unit Test (but sometimes also called an integration or component test) - Hit A down to the (approximately) level before an external resource (e.g database) - If the lower levels are complicated, but tested or if the lower levels are not complicated.
- Integration test - Hit A and the database.
- Full stack test - Hit the UI that happens to call A at some point - I'd aim to have at least a few at either this level (as Cukes or the like), or the level below.

As long as you have some of the higher level test, they should fail even if test that hit A isolation don't.

¹ Just using the phrase "pure unit tests" as some people have it their heads that the definition a unit test is method in isolation

Comment: what do you mean by "pure"? Just one class?

Comment: Aye. Its not what I'd define as a "unit test" but some people do so I'm giving it a name.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your unit test should penetrate all the way down to Class C. A **unit test** does not necessarily mean *ONE METHOD* on *ONE CLASS*. It just means that you can run it without needing other dependencies like libraries, or databases etc. Then you would need an integration test.

Your unit test should penetrate all the way to C, and when the requirement changes for A, then the unit test will break, and developer for D will know that something is wrong.

Comment: Unit means "a logical unit". In this case, the behaviour you're testing on D or A is defined in part by C, so include that in your unit.